# Comparison of rational numbers in GNU/Octave independent of numeric precision

Tags: octave, precision, equality, rational-number

The Octave interpreter evaluates this expression as false:

```
>> 2/3 + 1/6 == 5/6
ans = 0
```

cause

```
>> 2/3 + 1/6 - 5/6
ans =   -1.11022302462516e-16
```

This can be avoided with the `rat` (or `rats`) function, or casting the values, but the resulting expression lacks the clear formatting of the initial one:

```
>> all(rat(2/3 + 1/6) == rat(5/6))
ans =  1

>> single(2/3 + 1/6) == single(5/6)
ans =  1
```

When using Octave to teach kids arithmetic, 'dirty' translations of mathematical expressions are of no use.

Is there any global adjustment that could be done to evaluate as `true` the original expression?

Comment: Don’t use Octave to teach kids arithmetic. Use software that does symbolic evaluation, maybe Mathematica?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Octave is FOSS, Mathematica is something most worldwide schools cannot afford.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2F3+%2B+1%2F6+-+5%2F6

Comment: There are also FOSS alternatives listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems

Comment: @CrisLuengo A reliable and individual Internet access (I'm afraid) is something many schools cannot afford either, at least so it is where I live.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. From the list I linked, it seems that [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) (Python module) could do what you want (it requires some setup, but that is trivial to automate), or [FriCAS](http://fricas.sourceforge.net/) (the more active fork of Axiom, which looks stale). Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Julia has a [rational numbers](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/complex-and-rational-numbers/#Rational-Numbers-1) type and is free. You don't need to use Octave symbolics. You can use a [Jupyter notebook.](http://jupyter.org/) Note that notebooks make great teaching tools. My professor used these to teach. Some examples are [here.](https://github.com/johnfgibson/whyjulia)

```
2//3+1//6
```

5//6